# Formatting numeric output in a text box

Tags: formatting, vb.net-2010

Hey guys I'm working on formatting output to/from a text box, does the command  `variable = variable(format("""###########,"""))`  only take numbers, or do letters work as well? Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: @Raymond I meant was it only numbers or could it be letters? Please dont edit it until you really read what I'm asking.

Comment: If you found your answer, please post it...

Comment: @Brandon If you had given it a title better than "Visual Basic 2010" then I wouldn't have needed to edit it. A bad title is grounds for closure as Too Localized (unlikely to help future visitors).

Answer (score 0):

Yes that format only works for numbers, use the code 
 `variable_array = Split(variable, vbCrLf) For i As Integer = 0 To variable_array.Length - 1' loop through the array "variable_array" and do something with each array member
            variableformatted = variableformatted & """" & name_array(i) & """," & vbCrLf
      Next`